# Twig sandboxing not working for me

Tags: php, twig

Playing around with twig templates (not a part of Symfony, in CodeIgniter) and it doesn't look like I can get a global sandbox to work correctly.  I'm pretty sure I'm just doing something stupid, but I really can't see it.

Functions to make twig work:

```
    public function twig_setup($configs = NULL)
{
    Twig_Autoloader::register();
    $env = array(
        'cache' => config_item('cache_dir'),
        'strict_variables' => TRUE,
        'auto_reload' => TRUE,
        'extension' => 'php',
        'filesystem' => NULL
    );
    if (!is_null($configs))
    {
        $env = array_merge($env, $configs);
    }
    $this->set_extension($env['extension']);

    if (is_null($env['filesystem']))
    {
        $env['filesystem'] = VIEWPATH;  
    }
    else
    {
        $env['filesystem'] = VIEWPATH .'/'. ltrim($env['filesystem'],'/');
    }

    $this->set_filesystem($env['filesystem']);

    // These two things should not get set to the environment
    unset($env['extension']);
    unset($env['filesystem']);

    $this->set_environment($env);
}   
    public function set_sandbox($tags, $filters, $methods, $properties, $functions, $is_global = TRUE)
    {
    $user_policy = new Twig_Sandbox_SecurityPolicy($tags, $filters, $methods, $properties, $functions);
    $user_sandbox = new Twig_Extension_Sandbox($user_policy, $is_global);

    $this->twig->addExtension($user_sandbox);
}

    public function disable_logic()
{
    $tags       = array('for', 'block', 'include');
    $filters    = array();
    $methods    = array();
    $properties = array();
    $functions  = array('parent', 'block');

    $this->set_sandbox($tags, $filters, $methods, $properties, $functions);         
}
```

Usage:

```
 $twig = new TwigThing();
 $twig->twig_setup();
 $twig->disable_logic();
```

Now, once I render a template, I should not be able to use something like raw or url_encode

```
 {{ my_var|url_encode }}
```

That should kick out an error, or something, but it just encodes the var...wtf am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I guess the relevant code is missing here. What is your code in `disable_logic`? *Edit:* I don't think that you can suppress the rendering of the tags. Because if you want to do that, load the file yourself using `file_get_contents()` and just print it out.

Comment: you can--I think I discovered the problem.  It seems sandboxing may only work inside the tempate and not inside a file that extends that template.  This seems like a bug to me, I feel like if you set up a global sandbox and you extend a template, you'd want the code inside the child to respect the sandbox rules.

Comment: Twig 1.6.2 fixes exactly this bug: http://blog.twig.sensiolabs.org/post/19488978346/twig-1-6-2-released